# JOptionPane, JTextArea, and JScrollPane, Displaying ouput

Tags: java, output, jscrollpane, joptionpane

This is a HW assignment given to the class and I believe I have everything working correctly but I am having trouble displaying all of the information I would need on the output. If you look at `TestCashier.java` you can see my intended output. I need to know how to make `generateReceipt()`, `average()`, `makeChange()`, and `tendered()` display on the pane as well. Any help at all will be appreciated. I have been stuck on this portion for quite some time.

If anyone would like to take the extra step in helping me out on my `add()` and figure out why I can't get it to work when asking the user for each item price. I needed the total to work using `add()` but I can only get my program to work properly when I manually add them together and assign that value to `totalSum`. Thank you for taking the time to read this and all input/feedback is appreciated. (Even criticism...I am here to learn)

Cashier.java

```
package cashier;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Cashier {
    static int numItems;
    static double totalSum,averagePrice,price;
    private int   pennies,nickles, dimes, quarters, dollars;
    private double tendered,change;

    public void Cashier(){
        this.numItems = 0;
        this.totalSum = 0;
    }

    public void average(){
       averagePrice = totalSum/numItems; 
       NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       System.out.println("The average price per item is "+ nf1.format(averagePrice));//Must format

    }
      public void add(String name, Double price) {
        numItems++;
        //totalSum =+price;
    }


    public void tendered(double t) {
       this.tendered = t;
       this.change = tendered - totalSum;
       NumberFormat df1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       System.out.println("Amount tendered is " + df1.format(tendered));
   }

    void makeChange(Cashier c){

        change = (tendered-totalSum);
        change =change*100;
        NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println("The change is: " + df.format(change/100)+"\n");//Must format


        dollars = (int)(change/100);
        change %= 100;


        quarters = (int) (change/25);
        change %=25;


        dimes = (int) (change/10);
        change = change%10;


        nickles = (int) (change/5);
        change = change%5;

        pennies = (int)change;

        System.out.println("The change includes...");
        System.out.println(dollars+" dollars");
        System.out.println(quarters+" quarters");
        System.out.println(dimes+" dimes");
        System.out.println(nickles+" nickles");
        System.out.println(pennies+" pennies");

    }






}
```

GetData.java

```
package cashier;


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class GetData {

    static double getDouble(String c){
        return Double.parseDouble(getWord(c));
    }

    static String getWord(String c){
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(c);
    }


}
```

TestCashier.java

```
package cashier;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



import static cashier.Cashier.totalSum;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestCashier{

    public static void main(String[]arg){
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        Cashier c = new Cashier();

        String name = GetData.getWord(" Enter name of first item");
        double price = GetData.getDouble("Enter price of item");
        c.add(name,price);


        String name2 = GetData.getWord(" Enter name of second item");
        double price2 = GetData.getDouble("Enter price of item");
        c.add(name2,price2);

        String name3 = GetData.getWord(" Enter name of third item");
        Double price3 = GetData.getDouble("Enter price of item");
        c.add(name3,price3);

        String name4 = GetData.getWord(" Enter name of fourth item");
        Double price4 = GetData.getDouble("Enter price of item");
        c.add(name4,price4);

        totalSum = price+price2+price3+price4;



        //make payment 
        double tendered = GetData.getDouble("Enter amount of money for payment");



        generateReceipt(c);
        NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String s = (name+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price));
        s = s +("\n"+name2+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price2));
        s = s +("\n"+name3+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price3));
        s = s +("\n"+name4+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price4));
        s = s +("\n"+"_______________________________");
        s = s +("\n"+"Total:\t\t"+nf1.format(totalSum));


        s = s +("\n\n"+"The number of items purchased is "+Cashier.numItems+" item(s)");


        c.tendered(tendered);
        c.makeChange(c);

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s,30,30);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,"THE RIP-OFF STORE",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);



    }
    static void generateReceipt(Cashier c){

       Date current = new Date();
       DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
       System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE RIP-OFF STORE!");
       System.out.println("Home of the 'not so good' deals...");
       System.out.println("Thank you for stopping by on "+ df.format(current));
       System.out.println("");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your functions to concatenate to a string and return the string. In your function `generateReceipt()`, edit like so:

```
static String generateReceipt(Cashier c){
    String s = "";
    Date current = new Date();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
    s += ("WELCOME TO THE RIP-OFF STORE!\n");
    s += ("Home of the 'not so good' deals...\n");
    s += ("Thank you for stopping by on "+ df.format(current)) + "\n\n";
    return s;
}
```

and to get the information from that function simply call it like so:

`String s = generateReceipt(c);`

The same goes for all the functions you need output for from your `Cashier.java` class. I won't show you each function since it is the same idea for each one. Remember it will be called like so:

`s += c.average();`

Here is all of your string concatenation from TestCashier and how I have it:

```
    String s = generateReceipt(c);
    NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    s += (name+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price));
    s = s +("\n"+name2+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price2));
    s = s +("\n"+name3+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price3));
    s = s +("\n"+name4+"\t\t"+nf1.format(price4));
    s = s +("\n"+"_______________________________");
    s = s +("\n"+"Total:\t\t"+nf1.format(totalSum));


    s = s +("\n\n"+"The number of items purchased is "+Cashier.numItems+" item(s)");

    s += c.average();
    s += c.tendered(tendered);
    s += c.makeChange(c);

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s,30,30);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,"THE RIP-OFF STORE",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I haven't looked at your add() function but I'd be happy, too. Chat with me if you need any help.

**Here is a imgur link to what the output looks like on my IDE (IntelliJ Idea):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXEu9.jpg

EDIT:

You almost had you're add function correct. In `Cashier.java`, your `add()` had a statement commented out:

`totalSum =+ price;` just switch the operators `totalSum += price;`

Create a getter like `getTotalSum()` or something along those lines because you always want to use getters and setters instead of accessing class variables directly (at least in most cases). Call it in your `TestCashier.java` like `totalSum = c.getTotalSum();` and it should work correctly. Note how you have `name` as a parameter for your `add()` function. Why is that? If you don't need it or use it, scrap it.